# An explicitly centered TikZ picture is pushed far to the right when the document's language is set as Hebrew via the babel package

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, babel, hebrew, adjustbox

The following LaTeX code was saved in `~/test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox,tikz}

%\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
%\babelprovide[main]{hebrew}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{center}
   \tikz \draw (0,0) rectangle (8,1);
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

Then the following command was executed in the Terminal: `lualatex ~/test`. Consequently, the file `~/test.pdf` was generated. When opened in a PDF viewer, the file displayed as follows. (The page number was deliberately excluded from the screenshot.)

[image: No babel]

Note that the rectangle is horizontally centered on the page, as proscribed by the `adjustbox` environment.

I now uncommented the two commented lines, and reran `lualatex ~/test`. A file `~/test.pdf` was generated. When opened in a PDF viewer, the file displayed as follows. (The page number was deliberately excluded from the screenshot.)

[image: With babel]

Note that the rectangle is no longer horizontally centered on the page. In fact, it extends beyond the page's right edge.

Why does the `babel` code affect the explicit positioning of the rectangle? How can this be fixed?

Comment: It seems that the contents of the `tikzpicture` is wrongly anchored a the east side of its bounding box instead of a the west side. As workaround, you can change the language before the `tikzpicture` to English and afterwards back to Hebrew using `\selectlanguage{}` to overcome this problem. Not a really satisfactory solution though ...

Comment: @JasperHabicht There's the experimental `layout=graphics` option which attempts to fix graphics so that they're LTR.

Comment: It’s not that `babel` affects the positioning, but rather it doesn’t change it by default. Even if the text is RTL, the direction of graphic coordinates, including the reference point, are always the same, so packages must be patched somehow to compensate this (and each package has devised its own solution for creating the box).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To fix this, add the option `layout=graphics` to Babel:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox,tikz}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=graphics]{babel}
\babelprovide[main]{hebrew}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{center}
   \tikz \draw (0,0) rectangle (8,1);
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

This option was added in Babel 3.32, and the manual describes it as:

> modifies the picture environment so that the whole figure is L but the text is R. It does not work with the standard picture, and pict2e is required. It attempts to do the same for pgf/tikz. Somewhat experimental.